# Lutron Sunnata LED+ Dimmer on 4-way Mutli switch delays other switches on by 2 seconds

Tags: switch, light, dimmer-switch

I have a 3 switches - I replaced one of the auxiliary switches with the dimmer switch and while it works perfectly fine from that switch, the other 2 switches now have a delay when you turn on the light from those locations.

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Lutron Switch - Lutron Sunnata Touch Dimmer Switch with Wallplate with LED+ Advanced Technology, for LED and Incandescent, 3 Way/Multi Location, STCL-153MW-WH, White

Comment: I have dimmable LEDs and have largely given up on LED dimmers due to a half-second delay. 2 seconds would drive me around the bend. Plain switch and the lights come on instantly. I don't need dimming that much, most places.

Comment: I have removed all dimmers except in the bedroom.They just werent needed.